# Como mandar un registro de una celda DataGridView a un textbox de otro formulario?

Tags: c#, .net

**Lo que quiero hacer es que al dar click en modificar me mande a otro formulario para editar y que aparescan los datos en los textbox, pero no se que hago mal?.  Alli esta el codigo del datagridview**

```
 private void dgvDocente_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            Agregardocente vern = new Agregardocente();
            vern.txtnombred.Tag = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["IdDocente"].Value.ToString());
            Agregardocente verno = new Agregardocente();
            verno.txtnombred.Text = dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString();
            Agregardocente vera = new Agregardocente();
            vera. txtapellidod.Text = dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Apellidos"].Value.ToString();
            if (dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Cedula"].Value == null)
            {
                Agregardocente verc = new Agregardocente();
                verc.txtcedulad.Text = "";
            }

            else
            {
                Agregardocente verc = new Agregardocente();
                verc.txtcedulad.Text = dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Cedula"].Value.ToString();
            }
            Agregardocente veres = new Agregardocente();
            veres. txtespecialidadd.Text = dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Especialidad"].Value.ToString();
            Agregardocente verd = new Agregardocente();
            verd.txtdirecciond.Text = dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Direccion"].Value.ToString();
            if (dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Telefono"].Value == null)
            {
                Agregardocente vert = new Agregardocente();
                vert.txttelefonod.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                Agregardocente vert = new Agregardocente();
                vert.txttelefonod.Text = dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Telefono"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }



        ActualizarLista();
    }
```

[image]

[image: Alli esta el codigo del datagridview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien el código, ¿Agregardocente es la clase de tu formulario? no entiendo porque creas varias instancias de ese tipo, y no veo donde mandes llamar a tu formulario, algo como:

```
vern.ShowDialog();
```

Yo lo que haría en tu caso es crear una clase que tenga todos los campos que necesitas en tu formulario:

```
public class Docente
{
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    public string Apellido {get;set;}
    public string Cedula {get;set;}
    public string Especialidad {get;set;}
    public string Direccion {get;set;}
    public string Telefono {get;set;}
}
```

Luego, a tu formulario le agregaría una propiedad de ese tipo y lo inicializas en el constructor:

```
public partial class Agregardocente : Form
{
    public Agregardocente()
    {
        Dato = new Docente();
    }
    .
    .
    .
    public Docente Dato {get;set;}
```

Y en el Load, llenas tus Textbox con los datos de esa propiedad:

```
private void Agregardocente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Text = Dato.Nombre;
    textbox2.Text = Dato.Apellido;
    // etc...
}
```

y en el evento click del botón guardar, reemplazas los valores de esa propiedad Dato con los de los textbox:

```
private void guardarbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dato.Nombre = textbox1.Text;
    Dato.Apellido = textbox2.Text;
    // etc.
}
```

Y en el método dgvDocente_CellClick que pones de ejemplo, en vez de todas esas llamadas haces eso:

```
private void dgvDocente_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        Agregardocente vern = new Agregardocente();
        vern.Dato.Nombre = dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString();
        vern.Dato.Apellido = dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Apellidos"].Value.ToString();
        // etc
        if (vern.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
             // aquí ya puedes obtener los cambios que se hicieron en el formulario en la propiedad Dato
             dgvDocente.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Nombre"].Value = vern.Dato.Nombre;
```

Eso si, desconozco como tienes hechos tus formularios.